# Call sql server stored procedure in Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure

```
exec dbo.update_candidate "ur", 0
```

where "ur",0 -is paramtrs

But if it is called in the program, it does not work:

```
params = list()
name1 = "ur"
voises1 = "1"
params1=(name1,voises1)
cursor.execute("{CALL update_candidate (?,?)}",params1)
```

Comment: Please define `it does not work`? Do you get an error? It just doesn't execute? Do you have an open connection to the SQL Server?

Comment: Can you give more details of the error and the code? are you using pyodbc?

Answer (score 1):

In Pyton

```
   params2=(name1,'5')
   cursor.execute("exec dbo.update_candidate %s,%s" % params2)
   cursor.commit()
```

In SQLServer:

```
exec dbo.update_candidate "Hadjr", 2
```